# IP addresses for Windows Azure servers seem to be from the US, when the servers are supposed to be located in Europe

Tags: azure, geolocation, geoip

I have a couple of test servers on Windows Azure.  One is in the North Europe location and the other is in West Europe.  I yet to get around to testing which location offers better connection speeds from where I am (London, UK).

The Northern Europe Azure datacentre is apparently in Ireland and the West Europe datacentre is in the Netherlands, which is weird in itself I think.

But what I am confused about are the IP addresses are both 168.63.xxx.xxx.  GeoIP lookup says that they are both located in the US, and traceroute from London to the addresses get to the US before failing to respond pings.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has probably run out of US address space and is handing out adresses from different countries.

Comment: I forgot that I asked this question, but I remember reading recently that this is indeed the case - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/06/13/microsoft_runs_out_of_us_ipv4_addresses_for_azure_servers/

Answer (score 2):

1. GeoIP isn't accurate for every IP address. MaxMind do [take submissions](http://www.maxmind.com/app/correction), though, when you find an error.
2. I tracerouted a random IP address in that subnet and wound up in Amsterdam. Without a specific IP address, or at least a traceroute output, I don't think anybody but Microsoft could say. And they'll ask for one or both of those, as well.

Comment: `168.63.128.0/17` is advertised by AS8069 which seems to live in Asia, while `168.63.0.0/17` belongs to AS8075 does appear to head over the Europe.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?